# Is there a way to change the way R labels the interaction parameter in model output?

Tags: r, interaction

I am having a seemingly simple but very frustrating problem. When you run a model with an interaction term in R, R names the parameter generated "var1:var2" etc. Unfortunately, this naming convention prevents me from calculating predicted values and CI's where newdata is required, because  ":" is not a character that can be included in a column header, and the names in the original data frame must exactly match those in newdata. Has anyone else had this problem?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
wemedist2.exp = glm(survive/trials ~ sitedist + type + sitedist*type + roaddist, family =          binomial(logexp(wemedata$expos)), data=wemedata)
summary(wemedist2.exp)
wemepredict3 = with(wemedata, data.frame(sitedist=mean(sitedist),roaddist=mean(roaddist),    type=factor(1:2))) 
wemepredict3 = cbind(wemepredict3, predict(wemedist2.exp, newdata = wemepredict3, type = "link", se = TRUE))
```

This produces a table with predicted values for each of the variables at the specified levels, but not interaction.

Comment: `:` can be used in names, e.g. `d <- data.frame('a:b'=1:3, check.names=FALSE)`.

Comment: ahh thanks I was missing the quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `newdata` data frame, you shouldn't include columns for the interactions. The product of the interactive variables will be calculated for you (and multiplied by the estimated coefficient) when calling `predict`.

For example:

1. Create some dummy data:

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   n <- 10000
   X <- data.frame(x1=runif(n), x2=runif(n))
   X$x1x2 <- X$x1 * X$x2

   head(X)
   #          x1         x2        x1x2
   # 1 0.2655087 0.06471249 0.017181728
   # 2 0.3721239 0.67661240 0.251783646
   # 3 0.5728534 0.73537169 0.421260147
   # 4 0.9082078 0.11129967 0.101083225
   # 5 0.2016819 0.04665462 0.009409393
   # 6 0.8983897 0.13091031 0.117608474

   b <- runif(4)
   y <- b[1] + c(as.matrix(X) %*% b[-1]) + rnorm(n, sd=0.1)
   ```
2. Fit the model and compare the estimated vs. true coefficients:

   ```
   M <- lm(y ~ x1 * x2, X)
   summary(M)

   # Call:
   # lm(formula = y ~ x1 * x2, data = X)
   # 
   # Residuals:
   #      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
   # -0.43208 -0.06743 -0.00170  0.06601  0.37197 
   # 
   # Coefficients:
   #             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
   # (Intercept) 0.202040   0.003906   51.72   <2e-16 ***
   # x1          0.128237   0.006809   18.83   <2e-16 ***
   # x2          0.156942   0.006763   23.21   <2e-16 ***
   # x1:x2       0.292582   0.011773   24.85   <2e-16 ***
   # ---
   # Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
   # 
   # Residual standard error: 0.09906 on 9996 degrees of freedom
   # Multiple R-squared:  0.5997,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.5996 
   # F-statistic:  4992 on 3 and 9996 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

   b
   # [1] 0.2106027 0.1147864 0.1453641 0.3099322
   ```
3. Create example data to predict to, and do prediction. Note that we only create `x1` and `x2`, and do *not* create `x1:x2`:

   ```
   X.predict <- data.frame(x1=runif(10), x2=runif(10))

   head(X.predict)
   #           x1        x2
   # 1 0.26037592 0.7652155
   # 2 0.73988333 0.3352932
   # 3 0.02650689 0.9788743
   # 4 0.84083874 0.1446228
   # 5 0.85052685 0.7674547
   # 6 0.13568509 0.9612156

   predict(M, newdata=X.predict)

   #         1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
   # 0.4138194 0.4221251 0.3666572 0.3681432 0.6225354 0.4084543 0.4711018 
   #         8         9        10 
   # 0.7092744 0.3401867 0.2320834
   ```

**Or...**

An alternative approach is to include the interactions in your model-fitting data by calculating the product of the interactive terms, and then include this in your new data as well. We've done the first step in point 1 above, where we created a column called `x1x2`.

Then we would fit the model with: `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x1x2, X)`

And predict to the following data:

```
X.predict <- data.frame(x1=runif(10), x2=runif(10), x1x2=runif(10)
```

---

**If you have categorical variables involved in interactions...**

When you have interactions involving categorical variables, the model estimates coefficients describing the effect of belonging to each level relative to belonging to a reference level. So for instance if we have one continuous predictor (`x1`) and one categorical predictor (`x2`, with levels `a`, `b`, and `c`), then the model `y ~ x1 * x2` will estimate six coefficients, describing:

1. the intercept (i.e. the predicted `y` when `x1` is zero and the observation belongs to the reference level of `x2`);
2. the effect of varying `x1` when the observation belongs to the reference level of `x2` (i.e. the slope, for the reference level of `x2`);
3. the effect of belonging to the second level (i.e. the change in intercept due to belonging to the second level, relative to belonging to the reference level);
4. the effect of belonging to the third level (i.e. the change in intercept due to belonging to the third level, relative to belonging to the reference level);
5. the change in the effect of `x1` (i.e. change in slope) due to belonging to the second level, relative to belonging to the reference level; and
6. the change in the effect of `x1` (i.e. change in slope) due to belonging to the third level, relative to belonging to the reference level.

If you want to fit and predict the model with/to pre-calculated data describing the interaction, you can create a dataframe that includes columns: `x1`; `x2b` (binary, indicating whether the observation belongs to level `b`); `x2c` (binary, indicating whether the observation belongs to level `c`); `x1x2b` (the product of `x1` and `x2b`); and `x1x2c` (the product of `x1` and `x2c`).

A quick way to do this is with `model.matrix`:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1000
d <- data.frame(x1=runif(n), x2=sample(letters[1:3], n, replace=TRUE))

head(d)
#          x1 x2
# 1 0.2655087  b
# 2 0.3721239  c
# 3 0.5728534  b
# 4 0.9082078  c
# 5 0.2016819  a
# 6 0.8983897  a

X <- model.matrix(~x1*x2, d)

head(X)
#   (Intercept)        x1 x2b x2c    x1:x2b    x1:x2c
# 1           1 0.2655087   1   0 0.2655087 0.0000000
# 2           1 0.3721239   0   1 0.0000000 0.3721239
# 3           1 0.5728534   1   0 0.5728534 0.0000000
# 4           1 0.9082078   0   1 0.0000000 0.9082078
# 5           1 0.2016819   0   0 0.0000000 0.0000000
# 6           1 0.8983897   0   0 0.0000000 0.0000000

b <- rnorm(6) # coefficients
y <- X  %*% b + rnorm(n, sd=0.1)
```

You can rename the columns of `X` to whatever you want, as long as you use consistent naming when `predict`ing the model to new data later.

Now fit the model. Here I tell `lm` not to calculate an intercept (with `-1`), since the variable `(Intercept)` already exists in `X` and will have a coefficient calculated for it. We could have also done this by fitting to data `as.data.frame(X[, -1])`:

```
(M <- lm(y ~ . - 1, as.data.frame(X)))

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ . - 1, data = as.data.frame(X))
# 
# Coefficients:
# `(Intercept)`          x1         x2b         x2c    `x1:x2b`    `x1:x2c`  
#       1.14389     1.09168    -0.88879     0.20405     0.09085    -1.63769
```

Create some new data to predict to, and carry out the prediction:

```
d.predict <- expand.grid(x1=seq(0, 1, 0.1), x2=letters[1:3])
X.predict <- model.matrix(~x1*x2, d.predict)
y.predict <- predict(M, as.data.frame(X.predict))
```

Comment: jbaums-thanks for taking the time to answer. I follow you until the last step where I become confused; I don't understand how this yields predicted values for the interaction term and not just for x1 and x2 (that's what happens with my data). I want to try the alternative approach you suggest, but can this be done when one of the variables in the interaction term is categorical? I've added an example of my code above.

Comment: @user3500114 To do that you need to create indicator variables for the factor levels, and calculate the products of the continuous variables and each of the indicator variables. See my edits above.